# Program crash on startup

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, c++-cli, windbg

I wrote a simply program in Visual Studio 2012, using CLI/c++ (compiled for Win32). On my computer, where visual is installed (windows 8 64x), it starts ok, but when i'm trying to launch it on fresh system with Windows 7 64x, it is crashing.

First, it needed visual redistributable 2012, then net. Framework. But after that, it is crashing with simple "program has stopped". Okej, so i installed WinDbg and that is what it gets me:

```
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00f00000 00f1e000   SVCTangoProgrammer.exe
ModLoad: 77e50000 77fd0000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 73020000 7306a000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 763f0000 76500000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 75d70000 75db6000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
ModLoad: 715a0000 71676000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCR110.dll
ModLoad: 729d0000 72a55000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCP110.dll
(764.ac): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=06b10000 edx=000cdbe8 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=77ef0f3b esp=0036f938 ebp=0036f964 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
77ef0f3b cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 77740000 777e0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 75fd0000 7607c000   C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 75a10000 75a29000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 75a30000 75b20000   C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 759b0000 75a10000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
ModLoad: 759a0000 759ac000   C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
ModLoad: 72fa0000 7301a000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
ModLoad: 761b0000 76207000   C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 77520000 775b0000   C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 75b20000 75c20000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 772e0000 772ea000   C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
ModLoad: 77610000 776ad000   C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 775b0000 77610000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 77980000 77a4c000   C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 70f00000 71592000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
ModLoad: 73070000 73143000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSVCR110_CLR0400.dll
(764.ac): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
ModLoad: 6ff40000 70eff000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\51e2934144ba15628ba5a31be2dae7dc\mscorlib.ni.dll
ModLoad: 76250000 763ac000   C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 72910000 7297e000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
ModLoad: 6f5c0000 6ff39000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\e40da7a49f8c3f0108e7c835b342f382\System.ni.dll
ModLoad: 6f420000 6f5b1000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\72269ea7cc6281139e4d155e7c57dc67\System.Drawing.ni.dll
ModLoad: 6e800000 6f41d000   C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\22ae167d586450ad3a9b9a9ee43ebc86\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
ModLoad: 749d0000 74a50000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
ModLoad: 6e360000 6e7f6000   System.Windows.Forms.dll
ModLoad: 6e770000 6e7f4000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
ModLoad: 74490000 7462e000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
ModLoad: 728f0000 72902000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\nlssorting.dll
(764.ac): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(764.ac): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(764.ac): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(764.ac): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(764.ac): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
ModLoad: 74a70000 74a79000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\VERSION.dll
ModLoad: 6e690000 6e764000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
(764.ac): CLR exception - code e0434352 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=0036e0cc ebx=00000005 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=0036e18c edi=00000001
eip=75d7b727 esp=0036e0cc ebp=0036e11c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000206
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58:
75d7b727 c9              leave
```

It's easy to see, that there is some exceptions but i dont know how to fixt them. If it runs on computer with visual, it have to be some lack of dll's. So there is my question: Can you guys help me run my program? Oh, and also, if you need more information, please, tell me what do you need.

Comment: Do you see anything logged in the `EventLog` related to this app crash?

Comment: What does `analyze -v` tell you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer. I was using in my program some microsoft graphic libraries, that installs automaticly with visual studio. On clean Windows, there is need to install Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0.